# Using addition and subtraction in algebraic proving in set theory

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

I am trying to prove (using algebraic way) the following statement:
$A\Delta B=A$ iff $B=\emptyset$

So it goes like this in one direction:

1. $A\Delta B=A$
2. $A\Delta B\Delta A=A\Delta A$ (I added $\Delta A$ to both sides)
3. $B\Delta A\Delta A=A\Delta A$ (commutativity)
4. $B\Delta\emptyset=\emptyset$ (Symmetric difference between a set and itself equals the empty set)
5. $B=\emptyset$ (symmetric difference between a set and the empty set equals the set itself)

So, is it correct this way?
The thing that makes me wonder whether it is correct or not is mainly the addition of $\Delta A$ to both sides in step 2. I think it still maintains the equality of both sides but I'm still not sure if it is valid in proving.

And if it's not correct, can you offer me an alternative proof strategy (preferably algebraic)?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, your proof works and it actually shows both directions. Step 2 works because performing the same operation on both sides of an equality preserves the equality, and you're treating the operation like you would any other algebraic operation (symmetric difference with the power set of a nonempty set is a group, so you can do this sort of thing).

The only thing I see is that you are skipping parentheses between steps 2 and 4, which I guess is fine if you've already proved associativity, but if you wanted to justify every step with an axiom, you could write

\begin{align} (A \triangle B) \triangle A &= A \triangle A \\  
(B \triangle A) \triangle A &= A \triangle A \quad \text{(commutativity)} \\ 
 B \triangle (A \triangle A) &= A \triangle A\quad  \text{(associativity)} 
\end{align}

And so on.

Comment: Thank you, coldnumber! You explanation is very elaborative and detailed. Have a nice day!

Comment: Thanks, and you're welcome :)